# How to hide the Duplicate taxonomy values in WordPress?

Tags: php, taxonomy

I am displaying the area names using  taxonomy  in array format , each taxonomy have different area names and posts .When i click the area name it should pull out the all the posts from the all taxonomies , but my problem is area names are duplicating so i just want hide that duplicate area names  .Can any one guide me to solve this .

**Here is my Code :**

```
<div id="footer">
<h1>Area Names </h1>
<?php

            $taxonomyArray = array("health_area","schools_area","office_area","salonsandsaps_area");

            for($Inc=0;$Inc<count($taxonomyArray);$Inc++){

                $orderby      = 'name';
                $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                $title        = '';
                $empty        = 0;

                $args = array(
                    'taxonomy'     => $taxonomyArray[$Inc],
                    'orderby'      => $orderby,
                    'show_count'   => $show_count,
                    'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                    'title_li'     => $title,
                    'hide_empty'   => $empty
                    );

                wp_list_categories( $args ); 

            }
        ?>
    </ul>

    </div>
```

**Here is Screenshot of result**

[image]

Thanks in Advance .

**Screenshot of result  after updating code :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did not test the code. But this should be work.

```
<div id="footer">
<h1>Area Names </h1>
<?php

            $taxonomyArray = array("health_area","schools_area","office_area","salonsandsaps_area");

            $temp_array=array();

            for($Inc=0;$Inc<count($taxonomyArray);$Inc++){              


                $orderby      = 'name';
                $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                $title        = '';
                $empty        = 0;

                if($Inc!=0)
                {
                    $temp_array=array_merge($temp_array,get_categories($args));
                }

                $args = array(
                    'taxonomy'     => $taxonomyArray[$Inc],
                    'orderby'      => $orderby,
                    'show_count'   => $show_count,
                    'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                    'title_li'     => $title,
                    'hide_empty'   => $empty,
                    'exclude'      =>$temp_array
                    );

                wp_list_categories( $args ); 

            }
        ?>
    </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: @Renuka , I tried this but it doesn't work

Comment: @user2003956 After `array_merge($temp_array,get_categories($args));` part use print_r($temp_array);. So you can find that whether temp_array fill as we expected.

Comment: @Renuka , I did that , in the result some places it shows like this  "Array () Array ()" and still the duplicate area names are displaying .

Comment: @user2003956 I have done a mistake in one line. I edited the my code. Now try it. Even it won't work again use `print_r($temp_array);` let me the result.

Comment: as you said i updated the code and it doesn't work , then i use print the result not coming  properly, for reference in my question i have updated my latest screenshot please check it .

Comment: This is for to get clear idea about your code: According to your original code loop will run 4 times ("health_area","schools_area","office_area","salonsandsaps_area"). So there should be four lists. I mean `wp_list_categories( $args ); ` called 4 times. Can you highlight the those four parts separately in your first screenshot.

Comment: Hi please open this link(http://picturepool.co/highlight.png) to see the screenshot . i have highlighted the all the sections with red color border.

Comment: Are you sure that you have not registered some taxonomy multiple times?

Comment: Actually each taxonomy have so many areas(Area :Manama , Maqsha ,Marhooz ,Muharra..etc ), if i click any area it will pull out all the posts in that area .So what i did all the taxonomy values i am displaying in footer section. Here for example  taxonomy -1 has a area name called "Manama" and taxonomy-2 also have a area name Called  "Manama" so i want display the area name  one time(ex.Manama) instead of repeating twice  and when i click the  Area name (ex.Manama) it should pull out all posts from all the taxonomies in that respective area (ex.taxonomy-1,taxonomy-2...etc).

Comment: any solutions please for this issue ?